# Assign CSS variable to class that matches attribute selector

Tags: css, less

In an attempt to avoid having to duplicate lots of CSS code for a bunch of different variants of CSS classes, I am attempting to cover it all in one statement. Let's say I have the following layout:

```
.body[class*="card--"] {
    & .child[class*="card--"] {
        /* apply some styles if they body have the SAME 'card--' class */
    }
}
```

There are many variants of the "card--" class, such as "card--1" and so forth. I want to apply some styles to .child but *only if* they both have the same "card--" class.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible with CSS as described

Comment: This isn't an answer, but more of a heads up to use `^` instead of `*`. What you have will select any element if `class--` appears as a class, not just starts with, e.g. `something-class--`, where `^` applies only to elements that have a class that starts with `class--`

Comment: While this isn't possible in vanilla CSS, you can use Less to loop over an array of strings (or use an iterator if the classes end in increasing numbers). It will compile into a verbose stylesheet though. Another approach might be to use Javascript and apply a given CSS class or something when the two selectors match.